# checking if a string like 'hello' is a subsequence of another

Tags: python, string, loops, methods, find

it is a question which we give it an input for example

`ahhellllloou`

if it is possible to remove some letters or just ignore them in the example and at last we reach to `hello` it must `print('YES') else print('NO')` for example:

`input = 'ahhellllloou' output = 'YES' input = 'hlelo' output = 'NO'` - because in this input we can't reach hello word  it is `hlelo` not hello

other exmpale is `'hezzrtlilo'` which we can remove `zzrt` and i and see 'hello' and in this case answer must be true because at the end we see hello

other example : `input = 'tymbzjyqhymedasloqbq' output = 'NO'` - because in this input we can reach to helo which has one l instead of two ll

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Are you stuck somewhere in particular? This reads a bit like "Here's a homework question, someone post an answer." Adding some more clarity and any coding attempts you have made can help alleviate this

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Simply dumping an un-edited homework problem is not acceptable.

Comment: @gatsu--Are you asking about writer a checker to see if a word is a subsequence of a string.  A subsequence is a string that can be derived from a string by deleting some or no elements?

Comment: Iam checking if a string like 'hello' is a subsequence of another and I don't know how to write this code with an input that we catch it of user and check 'hello' string if it is subsequence of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming you're checking if a string is a subsequence of another.

```
# From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-two-strings-find-first-string-subsequence-second/
def isSubSequence(string1, string2, m = None, n = None): 
    m = len(string1) if m == None else m
    n = len(string2) if n == None else n
    # Base Cases 
    if m == 0:    return True
    if n == 0:    return False

    # If last characters of two strings are matching 
    if string1[m-1] == string2[n-1]: 
        return isSubSequence(string1, string2, m-1, n-1) 

    # If last characters are not matching 
    return isSubSequence(string1, string2, m, n-1)
```

**Test**

```
tests = [ 'ahhellllloou' , 'hlelo']
for t in tests:
  response = "YES" if isSubSequence("hello", t) else "NO"
  print(f'Test Word {t} checks as {response}')
```

**Output**

```
Test Word ahhellllloou checks as YES
Test Word hlelo checks as NO
```

Comment: thank you this is what I want but how would I be able to write this code with input that we catch it of user not input we give it previously to app